# Bootstrap List Group Item cursor: pointer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On the documentation of [Bootstrap List Group Items](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group), I'm having trouble identifying the CSS/JS that causes `.list-group-item:hover` to appear `cursor: pointer`.

I'm using the HTML structure exactly as in the example, and am including all the Bootstrap CSS, but am not getting the cursor like the example in the documentation.

I'm using the Linked items markup:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
</div>
```

Interestingly, the Bootstrap codebase does not include `cursor: pointer;` for `.list-group-item`-related LESS, so I think I may not have a grasp something else here, too.

Comment: It's almost like I'm missing `href`s

Comment: The `pointer` is implemented by the browser for anchors containing the attribute `href` (not bootstrap). Either you have malformed html, you're overriding the default implementation, or you're not including the `href` attribute. Check out this example: http://www.bootply.com/130861

Comment: Here is an extended example http://www.bootply.com/130867